# Android studio click the button to show message

Tags: android-studio

```
public void ShowMsg(){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No stock in this time.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ShowMsg();
```

After click the button, show message is not shown before next executing.

Comment: use Activity context rather than application context

Comment: Where is your onclick method please update your code

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add some delay if you calling method in onCreate

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {    
@Override.   
  public void run() {.   
     // Do something after 1s = 1000ms.   
     ShowMsg();    
  }    
}, 1000);
```